# Casting memory allocation return value to array of TYPE

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, casting, malloc

Trying to do the following in VisualStudio with no luck.
Basically I got type `TypeA` and I want to create an array of `TypeA`, lets say `TypeA array[10];`

But I want the array to be on the heap and not on the stack, because it will be huge (like `0x200000`) or something.

So, what I'm trying to do code wise is something like the following:

```
struct TypeA {
    UINT64 a;
    UINT64 b;
    UINT64 c;
    UINT64 d;
};

TypeA array[0x10000] = (TypeA[0x10000])malloc(sizeof(TypeA)*0x10000);
```

Comment: Why do you not use `std::vector`? Using `malloc` here at all without placement-new is technically undefined behavior and will get you into trouble for sure sooner or later should `TypeA` happen to become non-trivial.

Comment: A single array with over 2 million elements that consumes over 66 MB of memory (as you've specified) is usually a sign of poor design choices.  You need to give some thought to usage patterns (e.g.  how many of those 2 million elements will typically be *really* needed to be in memory at once).    In any event, in the rare practical cases where such an array is really needed in C++, use a standard container (like `std::vector<TypeA>`) rather than explicitly managing dynamic memory.   And get out of the habit of specifying array sizes in hex - that's just rank amateurism.

Comment: I don't want to use vectors. There is a reason for this design that I didn't describe because it is irrelevant to the question. I'm not sure that what I'm asking is even possible, but if it is - I would like to know how to do so the way I asked for.

Comment: @DanielCohen if you have exotic requirements that prevent you from using normal C++, you *certainly* need to mention them in the question. How else are we supposed to anwser?

Comment: @Quentin - Problem is, I doubt there are "exotic requirements" underlying this question.  Exotic requirements don't tend to make `malloc()` somehow more effective than using a standard container - since most C++ implementations which support `malloc()` also support standard containers (and their default allocators) effectively.   Exotic requirements are, practically, more likely to result in using a standard container with a non-default allocator (e.g. that uses some dedicated non-standard resource such as shared memory).

Comment: @Peter the issue is apparently (based on comments) that OP is using a library which expects a `TypeA (&)[0x10000]`. I'm pretty sure there's a way to make that work with an `std::vector`, but it'd be further than I'd want to go with it.

Comment: @Quentin - That can be handled, using a `std::vector` that has (at least) the required number of elements, an appropriate `typedef`, and a cast (for the vector named `v`) of `&v[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems to me that you want something like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array_wrapper {
    T array[N];
    // might extend with the remaining `std::array` interface
};

//...

auto array = std::make_unique<array_wrapper<TypeA, 0x10000>>();

some_library_function(array->array);
```

This way `some_library_function` will see a built-in array of type `TypeA` and length `0x10000`, but with dynamic storage duration.

---

Note that I am not using `std::array` because I am not sure that there is a  guaranteed legal way to obtain a reference to the underlying array (rather than its first element) from it, even with `reinterpret_cast`. It am at least certain that there wouldn't be if `TypeA` was not a standard-layout type.

---

Also note that `std::make_unique` will value-initialize the array, meaning that it will zero all elements. If you have some specific performance reason to avoid that, you can use `std::make_unique_default_init` instead in C++20 or (less preferably) before that:

```
using array_type = array_wrapper<TypeA, 0x10000>;
auto array = std::unique_ptr<array_type>(new array_type);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer despite not doing exactly what I wanted. I thought of this approach before asking but then decided it is worth asking if it possible to do the casting I wanted - it seems that it doesnt.

Answer (score 3):

As with all dynamic arrays, use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<TypeA> array(0x10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
struct TypeA* array = malloc(0x10000 * sizeof(struct TypeA));
```

Edit: Sorry, this is C

Comment: That's C, the question is tagged [tag:c++].

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an array. `TypeA array[0x10000]` declares an array of `0x10000` elements on the stack. The end. Full stop.

You can, however, have a pointer to the start of the array on the stack. This is what is usually done:

```
TypeA *array = (TypeA*)malloc(sizeof(TypeA)*0x10000);
```

Since this is C++ and not C, you should use `new` which exists for this purpose. Note that if `TypeA` had a constructor, `malloc` would not call it, but `new` would.

```
TypeA *array = new TypeA[0x10000];
```

Don't forget to deallocate the array with `free` (for `malloc`) or `delete []` (for `new []`)

You could also allocate a `std::array`: (this counts as a single object, so delete it with `delete` and not `delete[]`)

```
std::array<TypeA, 0x10000> *array = new std::array<TypeA, 0x10000>;
```

Comment: No raw owning pointers please. Use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Quentin gatekeeping? I think everyone should learn raw pointers before they learn smart pointers. Then, they understand what smart pointers are doing.

Comment: Just advocating that learning to use the langage wrong is not a prerequisite. Raw pointers are very much usable without breaking RAII by making them own resources pointlessly.

Comment: this wont work. I want `sizeof(array)` to return the actual size

Comment: @DanielCohen `sizeof(array[0])*0x10000`? I assume the `0x10000` isn't actually a constant?

Comment: I'm using a library that some of its function receives a reference `r` and later uses `sizeof(r)` for some logic. I dont want to rewrite the entire library.

Comment: Added a sentence about std::array

Comment: @DanielCohen That definitely would have been worth mentioning in the question.